# How to pull a pull request quickly locally

Tags: git, github

Before I merge a pull request I want to quickly pull the request locally and run tests and test out a few stuffs. I don't want to hit the gihub merge pull request yet.

I thought pulley would help http://ejohn.org/blog/pulley/ . But I am getting error

```
$ node pulley.js 76

node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
```

Is there any other tool that will help me quickly pull a "pull request"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check out a GitHub pull request with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567846/how-can-i-check-out-a-github-pull-request-with-git)

Answer (score 11):

Click the (i) on the left side of the "merge pull request" bar, it will give you the commands you need.

[image: new]
_________________________________________________________^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: The UI changed.  Now it's a link next to the button: ```You can also merge branches on the  command line.```

Comment: @Tekkub This does not work like this anymore. I have added an updated answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the following?

```
git remote add -f <test_repo_name> <test_repo_url>
git checkout -b <branch> <test_repo_name>/master
...test as needed
...merge if you like it
```

Answer (score 3):

*Taken from the official github page (in July 2013, but this may change):*

**Step 1:** Check out a new branch to test the changes — run this from your project directory

```
git checkout -b otherrepo-develop develop
```

**Step 2:** Bring in otherrepos's (where the commits comes from) changes and test

```
git pull git://github.com/otherrepoauthor/otherrepo.git develop
```

**Step 3:** AFTER SUCCESSFUL TESTING ! Merge the changes and update the server

```
git checkout develop
git merge otherrepo-develop
git push origin develop
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [Github help guide](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/) and assuming your remote is origin:

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick idea, why not create a local branch, then perform the pull on the original (remotely tracked) branch?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the fetch command

[git-fetch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html)

> Fetches named heads or tags from one or more other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete them.
>
> The ref names and their object names of fetched refs are stored in .git/FETCH_HEAD. This information is left for a later merge operation done by git merge.

In practice fetch gets all the named commits from the remote repository. This means that when going to origin, origin/master would be updated to point to the latest change on origin, but your local master is not merged, or changed to reflect these changes.

I'm assuming you're working on (local) master, which is a remote tracking branch of origin/master. You're branch names could differ, but the process is still the same.

You could now create a temp branch to do checks on origin/master by doing

```
git checkout -b temp_branch_name origin/master
```

which will create the temp branch, which now points to the latest history on the remote repository.

When you've finished testing and want to integrate, you can either do

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

which will perform a normal merge (as pull would've done) or

```
git checkout master
git rebase origin/master
```

if you prefer rebasing your changes, to get a linear history.