# How to pull a pull request from upstream in github

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I have forked a repo in github. There are some new pull requests in the `Upstream`. I want to pull a pull request from upstream locally.

How can I do that? I have no idea and found nothing related to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a pull request quickly locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389127/how-to-pull-a-pull-request-quickly-locally)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+pull+request+locally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check out a GitHub pull request with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567846/how-can-i-check-out-a-github-pull-request-with-git)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to do this by first adding the upstream as remote, and then pulling the pull request:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/USER/repository.git
git pull upstream pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

Where `USER` is not your username but the original one (the one you forked from), `ID` is the pull-request id and `BRANCHNAME` will be the local branch name corresponding to the pull-request.

If you want to push to your own fork later, you will likely have to set the upstream (from `BRANCHNAME`):

```
git push -u origin BRANCHNAME
```

Comment: And use `pull --rebase` if you don't want your PR to include the upstream PR's changes as well.

Comment: I also had to do the following:  ```git config pull.rebase false``` (to set me back  into 'merge' mode).  And then ```git config pull.ff true```  (vs "false" or "only" -- to allow fast-forwards again, but not require them).  Hope it helps.

Comment: after running the second command it showing `From REPO_LINK  ![rejected]        refs/pull/100/head -> main  (non-fast-forward)`  what thats means ?

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon You need to start from a clean branch, you probably have local changes (or commit) that conflicts the remote changes.

Answer (score 3):

See https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/:

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

where `ID` is the pull request number and `BRANCHNAME` is an arbitrary name for the new local branch.

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub API supports](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button) merging a pull request on the server using a PUT request.  So, you may do a PUT locally and merge a pull request.

But note that this just means that a merge happened on the server.  If you were on some branch, say `master`, and you remotely triggered a pull request, if you wanted the latest content you would still have to do a pull:

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull request is not a git feature it is a workflow and as such has to be followed if there is a need for replication. So the only way is to do the same locally.

```
git checkout featureA # as it has to be on origin
git checkout master/develop
git merge featureA
```

At this point you are in the state as the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - do a

```
git pull
```

to ensure you have the latest changes in master, then while on the master branch, do a

```
git checkout <branch name >
```

to the desired  that has the PR(pull request) and finally do a

```
git pull
```

while on that branch. I believe it should pull the current state of the brach that has a pull request.