# How do I get the code from a pull request on github?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am new to git/github and cannot figure out how to do this simple thing.
I want to pull (is that correct terminology?) the changes from a pull request, specifically [this](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/pull/1291/commits/266e703d66e812be1661d4ed64700f78dea9152a) one.

How do I do this?

I tried checkout but:

```
git checkout 266e703d66e812be1661d4ed64700f78dea9152a
fatal: reference is not a tree: 266e703d66e812be1661d4ed64700f78dea9152a
```

Comment: Its a merge request. Is it maybe as simple as that you want to checkout that branch? `LorenzReinhart:database-mysql_fix_tables` in this case.

Comment: Bear in mind there is no guarantee that the fork is up to date with the main repo.

Comment: Why do you want this? What if the pull request is rejected? Really you should wait for the pull to be commited, etc.

Comment: I want it because it fixes the code.

Comment: Ok, so I ask again, what happens if this pull request is rejected?

Comment: Read Liam's above comment.  There are caviats for cherry picking a single commit.  It would probably be better for you to try to work with one of the branches involved in the pull request, or wait for the PR to finish.

Comment: I don't care what happens. It is sql to create something the project is ignoring but necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a pull request quickly locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389127/how-to-pull-a-pull-request-quickly-locally)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+request+locally

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch it first. For example like this

```
git remote add LorenzReinhard https://github.com/LorenzReinhart/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server
git fetch LorenzReinhard database-mysql_fix_tables
```