# Checkout forked branch of repo without cloning fork

Tags: git, github

I like to do github code reviews, by checking out the code locally in my IDE.

If someone forks a github repo and submits a pull request, is there a way for me to checkout their code without cloning their public forked repo?

`my-repo` - I usually just `git checkout branch`

`my-repo-forked` - Here I need to `git clone my-repo-forked` and then `git checkout branch`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a pull request quickly locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389127/how-to-pull-a-pull-request-quickly-locally)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+pull+request+locally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check out a GitHub pull request with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567846/how-can-i-check-out-a-github-pull-request-with-git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may add the forked repository as a second remote to your local repo:

```
cd my-repo
git remote add forked-version [fork-url-here]
git fetch forked-version
git checkout [branch-name-here]
```

This way, you only have one local git for both your original repository and the fork.

More information about remotes can be found in the Pro Git Book: [2.5 - Git Basics - Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).