# git clone pull request instead of master branch

Tags: git, github

How can I git clone the PR which haven't been merged by the author in `github`? Tried to fork a repo but the pr is gone.

Comment: `git fetch upstream branch-of-the-pr`?

Comment: I don't own the repo

Comment: Yes, that's why I used `upstream`. `upstream` is the traditional name of the remote for the original repo of your fork.

Comment: @CharlesJr., do you have the original repo set up as a remote? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7244321/354577

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a pull request quickly locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389127/how-to-pull-a-pull-request-quickly-locally)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+pull+request+locally

Answer (score 2):

`clone` then `fetch` that PR to a local branch. For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/mimblewimble/grin
git fetch origin pull/2932/head:pr2932
git checkout pr2392
```

Note:

1. replace `https://github.com/mimblewimble/grin` with your source
   repo
2. replace `2932` with your source Pull Request number
3. replace `pr2932` with your desired branch name

I was looking for a single command to clone a single branch of a PR, but it seems not exist (please let me if somebody know that trick).

Answer (score 1):

By "clone the PR", I assume you mean: "having my local clone of the project at the state of a given PR".

You clone a repository, not a Pull Request. Git itself has no notion of Pull Request.
However, the Pull Request is probably associated with a branch, so you can do:

```
git clone url/of/your/repo destinationDirectory
cd destinationDirectory
git checkout branchOfThePR
```

If you already have a clone, then, as @JB Nizet said, you need to fetch the new branches:

```
git fetch remoteName
```

Then you can check the branch out:

```
git checkout branchOfThePR
```