# forking off of a pull request with git/github

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-fork

I am working on a project in github. A user has created a pull request. I would like to fork off of this pull request. How do I do this? I can't see anything that immediately stands out to me in git documentation, but I am fairly certain this is possible...

Comment: How about you create a new branch, merge the pull request and fork off it?

Comment: @NimeshNeema how would I do that though? This is a PR for upstream.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a pull request quickly locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389127/how-to-pull-a-pull-request-quickly-locally)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+pull+request+locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the original repo forked already. How would I bring the PR into my fork and branch off of it?

1. If you haven't already, clone your fork so that you have a local copy of your fork on your machine.
2. Add the repo from whence the PR comes as a remote to your clone:

   ```
   git remote add the-pr-repo git@github.com:the-pr-user/the-pr-fork.git
   ```
3. Checkout the PR's branch into your local repo:

   ```
   git fetch the-pr-repo
   git checkout the-pr-branch
   ```

Now you've got a copy of the PR's branch in your local repo, and you can build, test, whatever.

> This is a PR for upstream.

The PR still really just points to a branch. "Pull request" is literally a request to pull the commits from a given branch into some other branch. So let's say the PR is made from a repo called `basil` and specifies a branch called `basils-changes`, and the PR asks that the commits from `basils-changes` be added to the `master` branch of the `upstream` repo. I can easily get those same changes by first making sure that I have a local branch that's up to date with `upstream/master`, and then pulling `basil/basils-changes` into my local branch. That'll give me exactly what `upstream/master` will have if the PR is merged, so I can test the changes locally to decide whether I want merge the PR into `upstream/master`.

Comment: how can i branch off of the PR branch once it is added to my fork?

Comment: You don't "branch off the PR," you just pull the PR's branch into your fork using `git checkout`. If you want to create a new branch from there, you can do it again with `git checkout -b your_new_branch_name`. Or you can just make changes in your copy of the PR's branch. PR's don't change anything about normal use of git -- they're just a pointer to a particular branch. If the owner of the branch adds a commit to her branch and pushes it up to her fork, the PR will show that because, again, a PR just points to a branch.

Comment: is there any way to merge it into a branch i am working on?

Comment: It's just a branch, so of course you can pull it into another branch. Or you can rebase your branch on top of the PR branch. Doing the latter is often better if you plan to merge both the PR and your own branch into another branch (e.g. master) because it keeps the PR's commits distinct and helps avoid merge conflicts.

Comment: understanding what is going on is fine. i just want to know the commands to do this. god i hate git

Comment: The terms I used above map directly to the git command names. If you want to pull the other branch into yours, it's `git pull <the_other_repo> <the_other_branch>`. If you want to rebase, it's `git rebase <the_other_repo>/<the_other_branch>`. If you're not sure what the right parameters are for any command, append the `--help` option (e.g. `git pull --help`). I understand the frustration, but it'll get easier if you keep at it. Resistance is futile.

Answer (score 1):

PR's are based on branches. Forking a repository makes a new copy of the repository in your account including all pushed branches. Pull requests are not copied as part of the forking process.

Go to the pull request and find the branch it is based on:

[image: pull request showing branch]

Then fork the repository. You will find the branch in your new repository and you can recreate the PR or make another branch from there.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I have the original repo forked already. How would I bring the PR into my fork and branch off of it?

Comment: Then it's pretty simple. You just want to find the branch from the original PR, check it out and make a branch from it.