# How to check out a pull request coming from "unknown repository" on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I want to clone locally a Pull Request whose header in GitHub looks like this:

> [image: Pull request header showing "from unknown repository"]
>
> <sup>*^ «from `unknown repository`» is the actual wording, not a mock-up*</sup>

i.e. I can't see what fork or branch the PR is coming from.

Usually I would copy the name of the branch (with the "clipboard" icon), then do `git checkout name/of/branch`; but in this case the copy button doesn't copy anything into the clipboard.

How can I clone the PR locally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a pull request quickly locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389127/how-to-pull-a-pull-request-quickly-locally)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+pull+request+locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/168#issuecomment-374201226) in a relevant issue opened on GitHub, the PR can be checked out locally (assuming that you have cloned the repository) with:

```
$ git fetch origin refs/pull/<PR-NUM>/head:<BRANCH>
$ git checkout <BRANCH>
```

where `<PR-NUM>` is the PR number (in the example, "23") and `<BRANCH>` is the name to use for a branch that will be created locally, pointing to the PR.

If needed, you can make a new PR from `<BRANCH>`.

Comment: With the above command, why does Git says: couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/123/head