# How to git clone a pull request from the id?

Tags: git, github

I'm using the GitHub API to list PR's that have been made, from the information I have received I want to git clone the PR. Is this possible to do?

This is example data I am receiving from the GitHub API that I am using;

```
{
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347",
    "id": 1,
    "node_id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0MQ==",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347",
    "diff_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347.diff",
    "patch_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347.patch",
    "issue_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347/commits",
    "review_comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347/comments",
    "review_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/comments{/number}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347/comments",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "number": 1347,
    "state": "open",
    "locked": true,
    "title": "Amazing new feature",
    "user": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull a pull request quickly locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389127/how-to-pull-a-pull-request-quickly-locally)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+request+locally

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally